# "No viable overloaded =" nullptr

Tags: c++, matrix, rvalue-reference, move-constructor, nullptr

I have just started with C++ and am stuck on the move constructor. Here is my `.cpp`:

```
SimpleMatrix::SimpleMatrix(SimpleMatrix &&other_mat) {
 cols = other_mat.cols;
 rows = other_mat.rows;
 data_ = other_mat.data_;
 other_mat.cols = 0;
 other_mat.rows = 0;
 other_mat.data_ = nullptr; // <- Error here
}
```

I got `No viable overloaded =` error at `other_mat.data_ = nullptr`. What went wrong? Is it the way I initialize the matrix?

Here is the relevant parts in `.hpp` file:

```
class SimpleMatrix {
 public:
  SimpleMatrix(std::size_t nrows, std::size_t ncols);
  SimpleMatrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>> data);
  SimpleMatrix(SimpleMatrix&& other_mat);
  SimpleMatrix& operator=(SimpleMatrix&& other_mat);

 private:
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > data_;
  int rows, cols;
};
```

Comment: Since all of your types are RAII types there is no need for you to write any of the special member functions.  The compiler generated ones will work for you.  Also, think about what you are doing in `other_mat.data_ = nullptr;`.  Is `data` a pointer?  If it isn't, what would it mean to give it the value of `nullptr`?

Comment: You also don't need `rows` or `cols`. The vectors known there own sizes, they have a `.size()` member function.

Comment: `data_ = other_mat.data_;` is performing a copy of the data. You are not doing move construction in your move constructor, you are doing copy construction and then trying to clear the previous object which is not the same thing performance wise.

Comment: The "relevant parts in `.hpp` file" is missing one very "relevant part": The move-constructor definition itself.

Comment: You're right about the missing part @Someprogrammerdude. I have edited it. _Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data_` is a vector non-pointer *object*, and `nullptr` is to initialize a *pointer*  to be a null pointer.

You can't assign non-pointer variables to be null pointers. And C++ doesn't have any concept of null values or objects.

If you want the vector to be properly initialized I suggest you add a constructor initializer list:

```
SimpleMatrix::SimpleMatrix(SimpleMatrix &&other_mat)
    : data_(std::move(other_mat.data_))  // Move the data from the other vector
    , rows(other_mat.rows)
    , cols(other_mat.cols)
{
    // Clear the other matrix rows and cols
    other_mat.rows = 0;
    other_mat.cols = 0;
}
```

Or, you could rely on [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and let the compiler-generated constructors handle everything for you, which in this case it should do properly:

```
class SimpleMatrix {
 public:
  SimpleMatrix(SimpleMatrix &&) = default;
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Well, not entirely properly: the moved-from object will have an empty vector along with non-zero `rows` and `cols` variables.  To zero those without losing the compiler-assisted move constructor generation, a private base class could be used: https://rextester.com/SURN53114

Comment: This solves my problem. But more than that, thanks for a clear and super informative answer